# parameter function in v-model vue 3

Tags: function, vue.js, vuejs3, v-model

Hi I would like to use a function in a v-model (in Vue 3) like this :

```html
<template>
  <input v-model="sayHello('Jhon')">
</template>

<script>
export default{
  methods:{
    sayHello(name){
      return "Hello "+ name
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But the code returns this error :

```
VueCompilerError: v-model value must be a valid JavaScript member expression.
```

I googled the error and found that you're not allowed to use functions in v-model in vue 3. Does anyone know a way to do so anyway?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to bind a function to input? When do you want the function to trigger?

Comment: I would like the function to trigger whenever the value name ("jhon") changes like it did in vue 2. I do this because in my real code the data needs to be formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-model` isn't the right directive to use for handling changes to the input. If you want to call a function upon changes, use the `v-on` directive with the `input` event:

```html
<script setup>
const onChange = e => {
  if (e.target.value === 'Jhon') sayHello()
}
const sayHello = () => alert('hello')
</script>

<template>
  <h3>Type <code>Jhon</code></h3>
  <input @input="onChange" />
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-change-event-handler?file=src/App.vue)